# How to read CSV file using fxpoi package in flutter

Tags: android, csv, flutter, dart

I have a csv file with 3 rows and 3 columns. When I try to read this CSV file nothing is happening. I saw fxpoi and I'm doing anything exactly as the documentation says but I'm still not getting the results I'm expecting.

Here is the link to [fxpoi](https://pub.dev/packages/fxpoi) package.

**Note** The code below is executed after a button click.

```dart
import 'package:fxpoi/fxpoi.dart';
var activitiesFilePath = "assets/local_data/Activities.csv";

    int offsetLine = 0;
    int limitLine = 999;
    int i;
    var list = await Fxpoi.readExcelCSVByPage(activitiesFilePath, offsetLine, limitLine);
    if (list.isNotEmpty)
      for (i = 0; i <= list.length; i++) {
        var item = list[i];
        debugPrint("item: $item \n");
        debugPrint("item1: ${item[0]} \n");
        debugPrint("item2: ${item[1]} \n");
        debugPrint("item3: ${item[2]} \n");
      }
```

The code inside `if (list.isNotEmpty)` is not executing which means the CSV file is empty. This is where I don't get because I have a CSV file with 3 rows and 3 columns.

I want the code inside `if (list.isNotEmpty)` to be executed and the result should look like below:

```
item: names
item1: james
item2: jane
```

Thank you, posted with Love.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You need to use `rootBundle` to access file in `assets` folder 
You can read file with `rootBundle` and write to temp directory and pass path of temp directory to `fxpoi`

code snippet

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final filename = 'Activities.csv';
  ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load("assets/local_data/Activities.csv");
  final buffer = bytes.buffer;
  String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  String activitiesFilePath = '$dir/$filename';
  await File(activitiesFilePath).writeAsBytes(
      buffer.asUint8List(bytes.offsetInBytes, bytes.lengthInBytes));
```

demo output

```
I/System.out(28663): charset = asci
I/System.out(28663): line = a,b,c
I/System.out(28663): line = d,e,f
I/System.out(28663): line = aa,bb,cc
I/flutter (28663): item: [a,b,c] 
I/flutter (28663): 
I/flutter (28663): item1: a,b,c 
I/flutter (28663): 
I/flutter (28663): item: [d,e,f] 
I/flutter (28663): 
I/flutter (28663): item1: d,e,f 
I/flutter (28663): 
I/flutter (28663): item: [aa,bb,cc] 
I/flutter (28663): 
I/flutter (28663): item1: aa,bb,cc
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:fxpoi/fxpoi.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final filename = 'Activities.csv';
  ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load("assets/local_data/Activities.csv");
  final buffer = bytes.buffer;
  String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  String activitiesFilePath = '$dir/$filename';
  await File(activitiesFilePath).writeAsBytes(
      buffer.asUint8List(bytes.offsetInBytes, bytes.lengthInBytes));

  int offsetLine = 0;
  int limitLine = 999;
  int i;
  var list = await Fxpoi.readExcelCSVByPage(activitiesFilePath, offsetLine, limitLine);
  if (list.isNotEmpty)
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      var item = list[i];
      debugPrint("item: $item \n");
      debugPrint("item1: ${item[0]} \n");
    }

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```